# Banach spaces: A ball being a subset of the interior of the union of two balls

Tags: banach-spaces, computable-analysis, computability-theory

Let $X$ be a separable reflexive Banach space and let $A$, $B_1$, and $B_2$ be three closed balls in $X$. Is there a `handy' necessary and sufficient condition for checking whether $A \subseteq (B_1 \cup B_2)^{\circ}$, i. e., whether $A$ is a subset of the *interior (w. r. t. the norm topology)* of the union of $B_1$ and $B_2$?

If that is not well-posed, then let me phrase a more concrete instance: Let $X := L^p(\Omega)$, in which:

- $\Omega$ is a bounded and smooth subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, for some $n > 0$.
- $p \in (1, \infty)$ is a *computable* real number.

Now let $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{Q}$ denote the set of all balls (also called cells) of the form $(x_0,r) := \{ y \in X: \| y - x_0 \| \leq r \}$, where:

- $r \in \mathbb{Q}$, i. e., $r$ is a rational number.
- the centre $x_0$ is finitely representable (say, a piece-wise affine function having finitely many pieces with rational coordinates).

The questions are:

1. Is the relation  $A \subseteq (B_1 \cup B_2)^{\circ}$ on $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{Q}^3$recursively enumerable? In other words, is there an `algorithm' that takes three balls $A, B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}_\mathbb{Q}$ (which we know are finitely representable), and returns *true* if $A \subseteq (B_1 \cup B_2)^{\circ}$?
2. If the answer to the previous question is yes, then could the predicate be recursive by any chance? In other words, the algorithm returns *true* when $A \subseteq (B_1 \cup B_2)^{\circ}$, and *false* otherwise?

Some little notes:

- Whenever computability is mentioned, the framework is that of Weihrauch's Type II Theory of Effectivity.
- It should be clear that the interesting case is when $X$ is infinite-dimensional, as for the finite-dimensional case the answer is known.

Any help, or hint, or reference to related literature will be most appreciated.

Many thanks.